# Button using Action link

Tags: html

how to make this action link a button?

@Html.ActionLink("Medical Reps", "Index", "KOL_Image")
how to make this action link a button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using 'Bootstrap' like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Medical Reps", "Index", "KOL_Image", new {@class = "btn btn-primary" })
```